# Unable to execute anonymous block - Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I just installed postgres 9.6.2 and am trying to just run an anonymous block.

```
DO $$ 
DECLARE i integer;
BEGIN
  i:= 5;
END $$;
```

I keep getting the error:

> [ERROR    ] 2.0: syntax error, unexpected character

Can anybody tell me what is the mistake here?

Thanks in advance
Rathi

Comment: Which SQL client are you using to run that? Maybe it doesn't understand the dollar quoting?

Comment: It works fine in [rextester](http://rextester.com/l/postgresql_online_compiler)

Comment: Could be the Byte Order Mark ...

Comment: I am using the query editor of pgAdmin3 LTS  by BigSQL

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with pgAdmin3. I installed pgAdmin4 and it worked fine.